# Oracle VirtualBox not able to connect to the Internet when the host has slow Internet

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

VirtualBox running on Windows 8.1 has trouble connecting to the Internet, most likely when the host has a slow Internet connection. This happens occasionally and there are no issues with the Internet connection on the host machine [Windows] when the problem occurs.

- VirtualBox 5.0
- Host: Windows 8.1
- Guest OS: CentOS 7

Here's the network adapter configuration:

[image: Adapter 1]

[image: Adapter 2]

Comment: We are very badly effected with the issue, please share some tips to solve it.

Comment: Any suggestions please ?